# angular 1.3 can't find the controller function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to angular and tried to go with 1.3 new release.
Here is my code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-ng-controller="SimpleController"  >

<ul>        
<li data-ng-repeat="customer in customers">{{customer.name}} - {{customer.city}}</li>
</ul>


</div>
<script>

function SimpleController($scope){

    alert('done1');
    $scope.customers=[{name:'1name',city:'1city'},{name:'2name',city:'2city'}];
    alert('done');
} 
</script>
```

The console gives this error.

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.0/ng/areq?p0=SimpleController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
```

But when I change the angular source to

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Then it works. I use chrome.
any one let me know where can be the problem exists.

Comment: Try the unminified angular.js file. The error messages are usually easier to understand

Comment: @Phil. I tried `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.0/angular.js` . Still same. not working..

Comment: I myself am new to angular. Can you use data attributes for angular directives? Like `data-ng-controller` instead of `ng-controller`. Secondly, try a code like this: `angular.module('controllers').controller('SimpleController', ['$scope', function($scope) { /* ... */ }]);`. Basically, setup the controller in the "angular's namespace"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Global controller functions are no longer supported by default in 1.3. See [change log](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-6)...

> $controller will no longer look for controllers on window. The old
>   behavior of looking on window for controllers was originally intended
>   for use in examples, demos, and toy apps. We found that allowing
>   global controller functions encouraged poor practices, so we resolved
>   to disable this behavior by default.

It can be re-enabled with this config...

```
angular.module('myModule').config(['$controllerProvider', function($controllerProvider) {
  // this option might be handy for migrating old apps, but please don't use it
  // in new ones!
  $controllerProvider.allowGlobals();
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am very new to angular and suppose there are many tutorials and should be based on 1.2. If I move to 1.3 version with 1.2 tutorials, there can be problems like this. http://ng-learn.org/2014/06/Migration_Guide_from_1-2_to1-3/ also shows certain changes and I don't have any idea what all about them... Would you recommend any good start point/tutorial for 1.3 to learn from scratch.

Comment: Personally, I would learn 1.2 as most of the material out there is based on 1.2 . Once you're comfortable with Angular, many of these things will make sense. There are differences between 1.2 and 1.3 but the basic concepts remain the same.

Comment: How ever, when I add the code snipt you mentioned, it gives errors in console `Uncaught object angular.js:80
(anonymous function) angular.js:80
(anonymous function) angular.js:1799
ensure angular.js:1723
module angular.js:1797
(anonymous function)`

Comment: The code snippet assumes there's already a module called myModule defined. If not, change to `angular.module('myModule', []).config(...);` and then change `ng-app` in your HTML to `ng-app="myModule"`...

Comment: I don't agree with this decision. I think it is easier to do as it was before. And much examples on the internet will no longer work.  This will do Angular much harder to learn.