# AngularJS lazy loading breaks after 1.3.x migration, getting Argument 'XXCntr' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, migration

Hi we are currently lazy loading AngularJS snippets/templates and everything worked fine ... until we started migrating to 1.3. Now we're getting

**Argument 'WhateverCntr' is not a function, got undefined**

The thing is these snippets contain Angular template code and some script ... most commonly a controller or something like that.

The javascript that we're using is the following:

```
(function(angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('our.ui').directive('fwDynamic', [
        '$compile', '$http', function($compile, $http) {
            return {
                restrict: 'EA',
                scope: {
                    action: '@',
                    ajaxModel: '='
                },
                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    scope.$watch('ajaxModel', function(data) {
                        $http({
                            method: 'POST',
                            url: scope.action,
                            data: data,
                            cache: false
                        }).then(function(response) {
                            $compile(response.data)(scope, function (clonedElement, scope) {
                                element.html('');
                                element.append(clonedElement);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                }
            };
        }    
    ]);
})(angular);
```

Does anyone have a clue why it is breaking? We can't seem to find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a breaking change in 1.3 in that you cannot reference a controller via a globally scoped function. You must reference the controller by the name that was used when it was created on the module. If you are not adding the controller to the module explicitly you must now do that.

Invalid:

```
function MyCtrl(){}
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl"></div>
```

Valid:

```
function MyCtrl(){}
angular.module('myModule').controller('myCtrlName', MyCtrl);
<div ng-controller="myCtrlName"></div>
```

You can also reference this question/answer: [angular 1.3 can't find the controller function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25679182/angular-1-3-cant-find-the-controller-function)

Comment: Yes that was the issue, thanks. Also many thanks for the provided link. Didn't know what to look for so did not find that question/answer.

I am now disabling this new default ... for the time being.