# Latest angular version 1.3 and 1.4 are not supporting controller

Tags: angularjs

I am doing angular js program , but this functionality is but working with latest angular cdn but working with old  v1.2.28 and below ... but not with 1.3 or 1.4 cdn ,, any solution for this

```
 function studentController($scope) {
        $scope.student =
        {
            firstName: "john",
            lastName: "wrick",
            fullName: function () {`enter code here`
                var studentObject;
                studentObject = $scope.student;
                return studentObject.firstName + " " + studentObject.lastName;
            }
        }
    }


     <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <title>Custom Controller Example</title>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/ToutorialsPoint5.js"></script>

        </head>
        <body>
            <div ng-app="" ng-controller="studentController">
                First Name : <input type="text" ng-model="student.firstName" /><br /><br />
                Last Name : <input type="text" ng-model="student.lastName" /><br /><br />
                Your Full Name is : {{student.fullName()}}
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: what problem exactly are you having?

Comment: This is indeed by design, and in the Angular 1.3 Documentation for breaking changes.  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-22.  It has also been answered multiple times here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [angular 1.3 can't find the controller function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25679182/angular-1-3-cant-find-the-controller-function)

Answer (score 0):

http://wildermuth.com/2014/11/11/Angular_1_3_and_Breaking_Change_for_Controllers

var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("studentController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.student = {
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Wrick",
        fullName: function () {
            var studentObject;
            studentObject = $scope.student;
            return studentObject.firstName + " " + studentObject.lastName;
        }
    };
});