# Getting error in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am very new to Angular JS and implementing a functionality to save data. Here is my code-
script.js

```
function EmpCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.save = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "EmpWebService.asmx/SaveEmployee",
            data: "{'name':'" + $scope.EmpName + "','age':'" + $scope.EmpAge + "','city':'" + $scope.EmpCity + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.d);
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.d);
            }
        });
    };
}
```

Employee.aspx

```
<html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" ng-controller="EmpCtrl" ng-submit="save()">
        <div style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12px; margin-left: 450px;">
            <table>

                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right;"> Name :
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="txtEmpName" ng-model="EmpName" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
//rest code
```

After pressing F12 I am getting following error-
Argument 'EmpCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25679182/angular-1-3-cant-find-the-controller-function/25679323

Comment: In ng-controller  name of controller not a function check .

Comment: **Do not** use jquery's `$.ajax` when implementing angular apps.  Use the built-in `$http` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare an Angular controller likes so:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
  .controller('EmpCtrl', EmpCtrl);
```

Comment: I have downloaded source code from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/567376/ConnectingplustoplusDatabaseplusUsingplusAngularJS 
And its working correctly but when I am implementing it is giving error

Comment: Thank,your suggestion worked in my case but still confused why it is working in downloaded source code and that does not have declare controller

Comment: @RiteshGupta `.controller('EmpCtrl', EmpCtrl)` (or something similar) must be in there somewhere.