# Issue with ng-slelect in Angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have array like

JS:

```
$scope.array = [
{
 "column":"productdivisiondes",
 "dataType":"varchar",
 "displayName":"Product 2"
 },
 {
 "column":"productdivisiondes",
 "dataType":"varchar",
  "displayName":"Product3"
 },
{
"column":"productdivisiondes",
"dataType":"varchar",
"displayName":"Product5"
}]
```

HTML code:

```
 <select class="form-control inline" 
      ng-model="array[0]" 
      ng-options="option.displayName for option in array">
  </select>
```

Here is the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soumyagangamwar/f1687zd7/)** that I'm working on

I want default `ng-model="product2"` in my select.It's done

my problem is If I select product3 or product5 then my drop down down values are change as product 3, product 5, product 3.

Please help me to do that.

Comment: I am not getting your scenario lady. Will you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding I think you need to show default `product2` option at very first time. Once you change the option values it shouldn't effect as it is effecting in your snippet. Change your code by below one

```
<select class="form-control inline" 
          ng-model="nameDisplay" 
          ng-options="option.displayName for option in array">
      </select>
```

And in your controller

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';

    $scope.array = [{"column":"productdivisiondes",
                   "dataType":"varchar",
                   "displayName":"Product 2"},
                   {"column":"productdivisiondes",
                   "dataType":"varchar",
                   "displayName":"Product3"},
                   {"column":"productdivisiondes",
                   "dataType":"varchar",
                   "displayName":"Product5"}];
    $scope.nameDisplay = $scope.array[0]; //Assign the first value of array 

    $scope.addToSearch = function(searchval) {
       console.log(searchval, 'searchval')
    }
}
```

One thing you should remember over here. You are declaring controller globally. It is no longer supported with angular's `>= 1.3` versions. Your snippet is working because you're using `1.1`. If you are moving on with new versions, you should have a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25679182/angular-1-3-cant-find-the-controller-function) declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

Don't give `ng-model` to a value of existing array. that will update the array as well. `ng-model` is not a variable. Give a variable name to `ng-model` and initialize the value of that variable by

`ng-model = "selected"`

`$scope.selected = $scope.array[0]`

Here is the working **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f1687zd7/2/)**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    
    $scope.array = [{"column":"productdivisiondes",
                   "dataType":"varchar",
                   "displayName":"Product 2"},
                   {"column":"productdivisiondes",
                   "dataType":"varchar",
                   "displayName":"Product3"},
                   {"column":"productdivisiondes",
                   "dataType":"varchar",
                   "displayName":"Product5"}]
                   
    $scope.selected = $scope.array[0] //initializing the ng-model
    
    $scope.addToSearch = function(searchval) {
      console.log(searchval, 'searchval')
    }
}
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!
  <select class="form-control inline" 
          ng-model="selected" 
          ng-options="option.displayName for option in array">
      </select>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm p-l-6 p-r-6 p-t-3 p-b-3" ng-click="addToSearch(array[0])">
        Add
      </button>
</div>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS CODE

```js
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!
  <select class="form-control inline" 
          ng-model="option.displayName" 
          ng-options="option.displayName for option in array">
      </select>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm p-l-6 p-r-6 p-t-3 p-b-3" ng-click="addToSearch(option.displayName)">
```

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't be using the array value as a model.

Create an additional variable to hold the selected value, an use it as a parameter of your method.
HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    Hello, {{name}}!
  <select class="form-control inline" 
          ng-model="selection" 
          ng-options="option.displayName for option in array">
      </select>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm p-l-6 p-r-6 p-t-3 p-b-3" 
                              ng-click="addToSearch(selection)">
        Add
      </button>
</div>
```

JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.array = [{"column":"productdivisiondes",
               "dataType":"varchar",
               "displayName":"Product 2"},
               {"column":"productdivisiondes",
               "dataType":"varchar",
               "displayName":"Product3"},
               {"column":"productdivisiondes",
               "dataType":"varchar",
               "displayName":"Product5"}]

   // variable to hold the selection               
   $scope.selection = $scope.array[0];

   $scope.addToSearch = function(searchval) {
       console.log(searchval, 'searchval')
   }
}
```